# Latex cannot find reference in my LaTeX file - no .bbl created

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have the following article file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

In the same folder there is a `mybib.bib` file that contains the following code:

```
@misc{Nobody06,
author = "Nobody Jr",
title = "My Article",
year = "2006" }
```

When I compile using Texmaker, I get the following warning:

```
Citation 'Nobody06' on page 1 undefined
```

and a `[?]` is at the citation place.

I have been compiling the main file with `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` as suggested in [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number) . And no `.bbl` file is created.

The `.blg` file looks like the following:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: Appendix1.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: mybib.bib
You've used 1 entry,
            2118 wiz_defined-function locations,
            508 strings with 4242 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 576 in all, are:
= -- 56
> -- 26
< -- 2
+ -- 9
- -- 8
* -- 44
:= -- 90
add.period$ -- 4
call.type$ -- 1
change.case$ -- 6
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 1
duplicate$ -- 24
empty$ -- 44
format.name$ -- 8
if$ -- 127
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 1
missing$ -- 1
newline$ -- 8
num.names$ -- 4
pop$ -- 7
preamble$ -- 1
purify$ -- 5
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 20
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 37
swap$ -- 13
text.length$ -- 2
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 4
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 6
width$ -- 2
write$ -- 15
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: It works fine for me, i used `pdflatex` , `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me using pdflatex. seems to be a Texmaker problem.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen it should work with `latex` `bibtex` `latex` `latex` sequence as well and it worked for me only thing the ouput is DVI file instead of pdf. check in texmaker options if you have `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and `bibtex %.aux` in latex and bibtex locations. one can even automate the compilation using `latexmk`

Comment: Is the name of your tex-file  "Appendix1.tex"?

Comment: Thanks for your contributions. For some reasons texmaker did not work with the latex, bibtex latex latex combilation and by going into the terminal it worked. I do not know why. But it works know.

Comment: My guess would be (based on the "appendix1.aux" in the blg) that you had set the master file to the wrong file and so texmaker tried to compile something else.